# Cannot create new folder from context menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, context-menu

A user somehow deleted the ability to create new folders from the Windows context menu.

A typical correct context menu:
[image: A correct context menu]

The user's context menu (in this case, right-clicking an empty spot of her desktop):
[image: The broken context menu]

Sometime in the past week the Folder entry was lost. The user can still create folders by copying existing ones and renaming, but obviously that is a silly workaround. I know how to make a context menu entry for a normal file, but not for a folder. How is this repaired?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/265802d1367092273-new-context-menu-remove-restore-default-menu-items-folder_new_context_ment_item.zip

That link should help out. Download that zip, extract the restore registry file, run it, restart the computer, and hopefully it should be back!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following entries into the registry

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew]
"Directory"=""
"IconPath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,33,00,\
  00,00
"ItemName"="@shell32.dll,-30396"
"MenuText"="@shell32.dll,-30317"
"NonLFNFileSpec"="@shell32.dll,-30319"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew\Config]
"AllDrives"=""
"IsFolder"=""
"NoExtension"=""
```

All the values are of type `REG_SZ` but `IconPath` which has type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` with value `%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,3`

Alternatively, you can [download this registry file](http://malyek.net/misc/super-user/Folder-ShellNew.reg) and import it into the registry.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I checked my registry and things are already configured as listed above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the fix given by Alexey did not work (in fact, my registry was already set as he advised).

In my case I was not getting the `New->Folder` context menu option when trying to create a new folder in a sub-folder of the `My Documents` folder.

It turned out that something had gone wrong with the linkage that File Explorer uses to link the folder to the `Documents` folder in the top-level `Libraries` folder in File Explorer. It also had the side effect of making all of the existing sub-folder contents visible in a file listing of the affected parent folder.

I fixed the issue by right-clicking the `My Documents` folder and selecting the Take Ownership option. While this was processing I then right-clicked the `Documents` item underneath `Libraries`, selecting `Properities`, and then removing and re-adding my documents folder from the library. This resolved both of the issues I was having with the `My Documents` folder.

It may be that one of these two actions is unnecessary for this fix. I didn't know how the folder got into this state, so I'm not able to research the issue any further.